# Actions on timeline frames using baseclass in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swc

I have fla file with a movieclip. The movieclip has a baseclass where some actions are performed. This fla is exported as an swc. What I want is to be able to add actions to the movieclip from it's base class, without having to do it like onEnterFrame.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an undocumented method within MovieClip called [addFrameScript](http://www.as3dp.com/2009/09/23/a-closer-look-using-movieclipaddframescript/) which will do exactly that:

```
myMc.addFrameScript(2, myFunction);

function myFunction() {
   trace("this is the 3rd frame");
}
```

(the frame number is zero based instead of one based like gotoAndPlay's)

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a cheat sheet of these undocumented methods?

Comment: Do I need to garbase collect myFunction because somehow it doesn't get out of memory for some reason. 

private function():void{ this.stop(); }